# Determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm calculating the determinant of the matrix below. However the right answer is $-15$, but I'm getting $-30$. Can someone please point out the mistake?

[image]

Comment: hint :in second step you doubled determinant ,by $2R_2-R_1$ .note for the rules again

Comment: But while finding rank we can double any row while transformation... Why not when finding the determinant?

Comment: when we do row operation in $R_k$ we can replace $R_k$ with $R_k+aR_i+bR_j...$ but not $2R_k+...$

Comment: thank you ... That was really helpful...

Comment: Doubling a row does not in fact change the rank (the dimension of the span of rows), but it does double the determinant (which will be clear if you think about how it would affect calculating the determinant by (say) cofactor expansion).

Answer (score 0):

[Don't upvote - just a summary of answers in comments so question not unanswered forever]

The problem was a step doubling a row, which is not an elementary row operation. This changed the determinant.